# loop though excel files do something and save them to new folder python pandas

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, append, export-to-excel

I have am having trouble with a for loop.
I dont know what happened, this used to work, but now it tells me "No objects to concatenate".

I want to accomplish two things.
I want to loop through all excel files in a folder. For each excel file I want to remove 2 lines of header data (which the code below already does).

Then I want to save each edited file with its original file name in a new folder. But also, save a new file where all the data from each edited file is appended together.

I thought I had the append correct but for some reason it is not working anymore.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pandas import Series, DataFrame

appended_data = []

path = 'C:\Test\TestRawFile'
for fn in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(fn):
        # Import the excel file and call it xlsx_file
        xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(fn)
        # View the excel files sheet names
        xlsx_file.sheet_names
        # Load the xlsx files Data sheet as a dataframe
        df = xlsx_file.parse('Sheet1',header= None)
        df_NoHeader = df[2:]
        data = df_NoHeader
        appended_data.append(data)
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
```

Here is the error I currently get.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-962ccf280c0b> in <module>()
     11         data = df_NoHeader
     12         appended_data.append(data)
---> 13 appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.pyc in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, copy)
    832                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
    833                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
--> 834                        copy=copy)
    835     return op.get_result()
    836 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.pyc in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy)
    865 
    866         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 867             raise ValueError('No objects to concatenate')
    868 
    869         if keys is None:

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Comment: add the complete traceback to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the reason script worked before and not now is you moved its location from the folder of Excel files as this code uses relative paths. Try using absolute paths where you concatenate the folder path name to file name. Consider using `os.path.join()` which even helps in saving to new folder:

```
dfList = []
path = 'C:\\Test\\TestRawFile' 
newpath = 'C:\\Path\\To\\New\\Folder'

for fn in os.listdir(path): 
  # Absolute file path
  file = os.path.join(path, fn)
  if os.path.isfile(file): 
    # Import the excel file and call it xlsx_file 
    xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(file) 
    # View the excel files sheet names 
    xlsx_file.sheet_names 
    # Load the xlsx files Data sheet as a dataframe 
    df = xlsx_file.parse('Sheet1',header= None) 
    df_NoHeader = df[2:] 
    data = df_NoHeader 
    # Save individual dataframe
    data.to_excel(os.path.join(newpath, fn))

    dfList.append(data) 

appended_data = pd.concat(dfList)
appended_data.to_excel(os.path.join(newpath, 'master_data.xlsx'))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I believe you are correct. I cant see any other reason why my code would work one day, then not work the next. I recieve an error though with this code, it says the following: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sheet_names'

Comment: Ok I found out the issue. the xlsx_file = pd.read_excel(file) was creating a dataframe, I needed to go in and select the specific sheet, I changed it to xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(file). Now my issue is that the newly formated files are overwriting the originals files. I would like to save all edits in a new folder. (I think I can figure it out). Thanks!!!

Comment: I created a new path, AllFormatedFiles then changed data.to_excel(os.path.join(AllFormatedFiles, os.path.basename(file))) Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out. I edited accordingly where I mistakenly joined full file path with newpath directory. And you should not need to use basename as the loop's `fn` is the basename. Simply call: `data.to_excel(os.path.join(newpath, fn))`. Using `glob` would require basename.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

fmask = '/path/to/excel_files_dir/*.xls*'
target_dir = '/path/to/'
target_fname = '/path/to/result.xlsx'

dfs = []
for f in glob.glob(fmask):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, header=None, skiprows=2)
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(target_dir, os.path.basename(f)),
                index=False)
    dfs.append(df)

# save concatenated
pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).to_excel(target_fname, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the answer below. My actual code does more than just remove the two first rows, but I left that out. I used the os.path.basename aspect of your code though. so thanks!